# Unwinding multiple arrays of objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have 3 arrays made up of objects.  When I try to unwind them I get back several of the same arrays.  I don't get back a clean set of the 3 arrays as objects.  Below are the output of the arrays before I try to unwind them.  Is there a better way to unwind them cleanly?  Thanks.

{

```
  "amount_last_30_days": [
    {
      "_id": "credit card bill",
      "last_30_days": 4500.37
    }
  ],
  "amount_last_60_days": [
    {
      "_id": "credit card bill",
      "last_60_days": 1000.04
    },
    {
      "_id": "electric bill",
      "last_60_days": 7500.41
    }
  ],
  "amount_last_90_days": [
    {
      "_id": "credit card bill",
      "last_90_days": 1500.06
    },
    {
      "_id": "electric bill",
      "last_90_days": 7500.41
    }
  ],
```

}

Final Result:

```
{

 {
"_id": "credit card bill",
"last_30_days": 4500.37,
"last_60_days": 1000.04,
"last_90_days": 1500.06
},
 {
"_id": "electric bill",
"last_30_days": 0,
"last_60_days": 7500.41,
"last_90_days": 7500.41
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post what you would like the final data structure to look like

Comment: Final Result Posted.  Taking it a set further how would I group the items above to result according to the posted Final Result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `$concatArrays` to merge all the amount across days.

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project:{all_amounts:{$concatArrays:["$amount_last_30_days", "$amount_last_60_days", "$amount_last_90_days"]}}}
])
```

and you can `$unwind` for further processing.

Update - Add `$group` stage to sum amounts.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project:{all_amounts:{$concatArrays:["$amount_last_30_days", "$amount_last_60_days", "$amount_last_90_days"]}}},
  {$unwind:"$all_amounts"},
  {$group:{_id:"$all_amounts._id", "last_30_days": {$sum:"$all_amounts.last_30_days"}, "last_60_days":{$sum:"$all_amounts.last_60_days"}, "last_90_days":{$sum:"$all_amounts.last_90_days"}}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Veeram.  Can you help out on my last question commented above.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Updated answer to include the sum of amounts.

Comment: You are welcome. This is what I can do now .I believe answer can be improved because sum is not really needed as you only have one entry for _id/days range. Will add some notes and updates little later.

Comment: Thanks Veeram.  Appreciate it. I was noticing the same thing.

Comment: You are welcome.  As we are mostly doing formatting here, you should use the client side for this or use the provided answer. Your structure have dynamic keys and aggregation framework requires you to have consistent structure. You should consider restructuring your schema to make better use of aggregation framework for future needs.

Comment: Sounds Good.  Thanks again Veeram.